# I have to make getArrayStringLongerThan()

Tags: arrays, stringbuffer

I'm trying to make getArrayStringLongerThan() constructor that returns a StringBuffer array with COPIES of StringBuffer objects in the array parameter that have a length greater than the length parameter. If no strings are found an empty array will be returned. Down blew is all I got so far!

```
public static StringBuffer getArrayStrignsLongerThan(java.lang.StringBuffer[] 
array, int length) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++) {

        size++;
    }

    // String str="";
    StringBuffer buffers[] = new StringBuffer[array.length];
    int[] newArray2 = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0, position = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++) {

        buffers[i] = new StringBuffer(array[i]);
        // str += String.valueOf(buffers[i]);
        newArray2[position] = buffers[i];
        position++;
        // System.out.print(i + "->");
    }

    return buffers[i];
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your issue is - are you getting an error?

Comment: so i don't know if I'm in a right track and also how return a string buffer!

Comment: public static StringBuffer getArrayStrignsLongerThan(java.lang.StringBuffer[] array, int length) {
  if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
   return null;
  }
  int size = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length+1; i++) {

    size++;
  }
  StringBuffer buffers[] = new StringBuffer[array.length];
  int[] newArray2 = new int[size];
  for (int i = 0,position=0; i < array.length + 1; i++) {

   buffers[i] = new StringBuffer(array[i]);
    //str += String.valueOf(buffers[i]);
   newArray2[position] = buffers[i];
   position++;
  } 
    return buffers[i];
 }

Comment: I also edit my code again

Comment: I get error at  return buffers[i];

Comment: Is there any way you can help me? @AjahnCharles